# Is a starter relay needed to supply the current to the starter motor solenoid?

Tags: automotive-engineering

Considering the fact that the starter solenoid needs a maximum of 50 Amps initially (in order for the pinion gear to engage to the flywheel through the plunger and lever) and then some 8 Amps during cranking, do we need a relay to supply power to the solenoid? Is this relay of electromechanical type or a solid state one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier cars did not use a relay, as the ignition switches were built sufficiently well to carry the 50A current for the pull-in winding current.

Newer cars have components like the ignition switch that are lighter and have more functions and need a relay to drive the starter solenoid. This relay is usually in the fuse box in the engine compartment.

We had a Commer van (petrol) that the ignition switch had the following positions : off, ignition, start. Another van (diesel) had off, on, heat, start...

Most relays are the electro-mechanical type as they are cheap and easy to get hold of, but as cars get more computer well more micro-processor control then some things are being replaced with solid-state components.

Edit: here is a link kindly provided by a comment :

[example starting circuits](https://autosystempro.com/starter-control-circuit-components/)

It does not include all possibilities, early Landrovers just had a big spring-loaded push button that directly operated the starter - no relays, solenoids at all...

Comment: Might want to add an source such as this one - https://autosystempro.com/starter-control-circuit-components/